# run a function after a nested promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, promise

i have a utility function that check for items in indexeddb and invalidated them

```
invalidateCache() {
    let now = Date.now()

    return keys(cacheStore).then((keys) => { // 1st
        keys.map((key) => {
            return this.getCachedResponse(key).then((item) => { // 2nd
                if (item.expire < now) {
                    this.deleteCache(key)
                }
            })
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
    })
}
```

now i need to make sure that the 2nd promise has resolved before i chain into another function, like so

```
this.invalidateCache().then(() => { // 2nd promise has finished its work
    // check the db
    this.getCachedResponse()
        .then((res) => {
            if (res) {} // item is not expired
            else {} // make http request
```

but unfortunately the `this.invalidateCache().then(()` resolve to the 1st promise not the nested.

so how can i continue chaining after the nested `2nd` promise ?

Comment: Put a `Promise.all` around the `keys.map` and `return` it. It needs to know to wait for those internal promises and also `return this.deleteCache` since that's probably a promise too.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanx alot, that did the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` to wait for all promises:

```
 return keys(cacheStore).then((keys) => { // 1st
    return Promise.all(keys.map((key) => {
        return this.getCachedResponse(key).then((item) => { // 2nd
            if (item.expire < now) {
               return this.deleteCache(key)
            }
        })
    }));
})
```

This is slightly more readable using `async` / `await`:

```
 async invalidateCache() {
   const now = Date.now()

   const keys = await getKeys(cacheStore);

   await Promise.all(keys.map(key => this.expireKey(now, key)));
 }

 async expireKey(time, key) {
     const item = await this.getCachedResponse(key);
     if(item.expire < time) 
        this.deleteCache(key);         
 }
```

Comment: @ctf0 glad to help :)